# css3 on/off switch w/o images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, css

I'm looking for a iPhone like on/off switch that doesn't use images.

Something like this: http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html

but w/o using images. With CSS3 I don't see why images are required? Any one know of any options? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of tutorials for making Aristo-like elements:

http://socialistpear.com/journal/aristo-buttons-in-css3/

https://github.com/280north/aristo

They don't have that specific button you want, but it will help you design your own button in CSS3.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you are looking for: http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

A generator where you get the CSS3 and HTML after styling the toggle button (see end of page).

Comment: ?? Does the on/off value of the button bind to the checkbox? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you can see it yourself on the page above. Open Scratchpad of Firefox and run: `$('.onoffswitch-inner').click( function(){ alert($('input[name=onoffswitch]').is(':checked')); });` then click the on-off-button.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found this example that uses unicode # and CSS3...But I'm afraid it's not iPhone style but hopefully it can help you with something the button is really good looking take a look if you have the chance

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-on-off-button/